# Metodo void que hace que una posicion de un array cambie de valor

Tags: java

buenos dias. Estoy estudiando para un examen de programación y tengo una pequeña duda. Me piden sacar el output del programa, del siguiente codigo.

```
  class Ejercicio {
 public static void main(String [] args) {
 int[] matriz1={9,1,3,5};
 int [] matriz2=matriz1;
 matriz2[3]=4;
 matriz1[1]=3;
 metodo1(matriz1, matriz2);
 System.out.print(matriz1[1]+" "+matriz2[2]+" ");
 }//end main
 public static void metodo1(int [] m1, int [] m2) {
 m1[1]=4;
 m2[1]=m1[3]+m2[2];
 }//end metodo1
}//end class
```

Como es posible que sin operandos tras pasar por el método,
matriz1[1]=7 y no matriz1[1]=9

Es lo que no termino de entender. Muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando haces esto:

```
int[] matriz2 = matriz1;
```

Estás haciendo que matriz2 apunte a matriz1, no estás creando un nuevo array, por lo que hay un único array en memoria con dos variables (matriz1 y matriz2) que apuntan al mismo array. Por lo que todo cambio que hagas sobre matriz1 lo vas a hacer también en matriz2 y viceversa. Si quieres verificar que esto es cierto, prueba a inicializar matriz2 así: `int[] matriz2 =  {9, 1, 3, 5};` y verás como obtienes diferentes resultados.

Volviendo a la duda original, tienes inicialmente en el array esto:

```
{9,1,3,5}
```

Luego cambias la posición 3 al valor 4:

```
{9,1,3,4}
```

Luego cambias la posición 1 al valor 3:

```
{9,3,3,4}
```

Luego entras en el método y le pones un 4 en la posición 1:

```
{9,4,3,4}
```

Y luego le pones en la posición 1 la suma de la posición 3 más la posición 2 (3 + 4)

```
{9,7,3,4}
```

Por último imprimes la posición 1 y 2:

```
7 3
```

Comment: Osea que da igual si uso matriz1 o matriz2 para referirme a la matriz. Muchisimas gracias ^^